# Simple question: condition for when RSI below 10 for a certain number of bars

Tags: pine-script

I want to write a condition for when an RSI has been below 10 for at least a certain number of bars, like 3 for example. I'm not a complete noob for pine script but I can't figure out exactly how to do this.

Basically like if RSI has been less than 10 for more than or equal to **this many bars**.

EDIT: I was also looking to plot text on the chart when this condition occurs. This is the relevant script based on the answer by SafetyHammer. Nothing is plotted on the chart even when I look at the RSI and these conditions seem to have been met.

```
twopRSI=rsi(close, 12)

barsinput=input(defval=10, minval=1, title="RSI Value Threshold for Dip", type=input.integer, confirm=true)

mindip=input(defval=3, minval=1, title="Minimum Bars To Count Dip", type=input.integer, confirm=true)

RSIdip= twopRSI < barsinput

RSIdipbars = 0

RSIdipbars := RSIdip ? nz(RSIdipbars[1]) + 1 : 0

diptrue= RSIdipbars >= mindip

plotshape(series=diptrue, title="Dip Label", style=shape.xcross,
location=location.belowbar, color=color.white, text="RSI Dip", textcolor=color.white, size=size.normal)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, this will count the number of bars below 30, you can change 30 to any number in indicator settings. You are lucky, earlier today was thinking about counting bar when condition is true.

```
//@version=4
study(title="Relative Strength Index", shorttitle="RSI", format=format.price, precision=2, resolution="")

length          = input(title="Rsi Length",  type=input.integer, defval=14, minval=1)  // User input for rsi length
upper_bound     = input(title="Upper Bound", type=input.integer, defval=70, minval=0, maxval=100)  // User input for overbought horizontal line
lower_bound     = input(title="Lower Bound", type=input.integer, defval=30, minval=0, maxval=100)  // User input for oversold horizontal line


rsi             = rsi(close, length)


rsiplot         = plot(rsi,title="RSI", color=color.new(color.green,10))
upper_hl        = hline(upper_bound)   // Plot the hlines and assign to be used for fill
lower_hl        = hline(lower_bound)



barsinput       = input(title="RSI Value Condition to Count Bars",  type=input.integer, defval=30, minval=1)  // User input for rsi 
condition       = rsi < barsinput
bars            = 0
bars            := condition ? nz(bars[1]) + 1 : 0




fill(upper_hl, lower_hl, color=color.purple)   // Fills the area between hlines. Default color is pruple.
plot(bars, title="Bars Crossunder", color=color.new(color.aqua,100))
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't need all of that but thanks anyways. I'll try it out and mark this solved if it works.

Comment: Would you mind explaining how this works? I'm a bit confused as to why you're using `nz`?

Comment: Nz This function takes an argument and if it is equal to na then it returns 0. You can find more on it here https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v3/language/Expressions_declarations_and_statements.html#preventing-na-values-functions-na-and-nz

Comment: Thanks, I had figured that out not long ago. More specifically, I was looking to plot text on the chart when this condition is met. Please see my edit on the post for the relevant script. Maybe you can help me on this, because when I try to plot using `plotshape` I get nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Not seeing becasue

Being drawn far from RSI trend, so zoom out and you will see it or change location from below bar to bottom,

Or

You are using 10 to identify a dip, you are possibly not reaching RSI below 10 so you dont see it. Change it to 30 to debug, once it works back to 10.

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © SafetyHammer

//@version=4
study("My Script")

upper_bound     = input(title="Upper Bound", type=input.integer, defval=70, minval=0, maxval=100)  // User input for overbought horizontal line
lower_bound     = input(title="Lower Bound", type=input.integer, defval=30, minval=0, maxval=100)  // User input for oversold horizontal line

twopRSI=rsi(close, 12)

barsinput=input(defval=10, minval=1, title="RSI Value Threshold for Dip", type=input.integer, confirm=true)

mindip=input(defval=3, minval=1, title="Minimum Bars To Count Dip", type=input.integer, confirm=true)

RSIdip= twopRSI < barsinput

RSIdipbars = 0

RSIdipbars := RSIdip ? nz(RSIdipbars[1]) + 1 : 0

diptrue= RSIdipbars >= mindip


plotshape(diptrue, title="Dip Label", style=shape.xcross, location=location.bottom, color=color.white, text="RSI Dip", textcolor=color.white, size=size.tiny)



rsiplot         = plot(twopRSI,title="RSI", color=color.new(color.green,10))
upper_hl        = hline(upper_bound)   // Plot the hlines and assign to be used for fill
lower_hl        = hline(lower_bound)


fill(upper_hl, lower_hl, color=color.purple)   // Fills the area between hlines. Default color is pruple.
```

Comment: Ah I see. Yeah it seems like in my specific situation it just wasn't reaching 10, but I changed it to 30 and it seemed to be working. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's plotting a hell of a lot even for the same 'dip'. I'm wondering if there's a way to have it just plot once for one 'dip'. Thanks for the help anyways.

https://ibb.co/0QFghp9 

screenshot